# searching method using certain keyword to give desired output

Tags: c++

here i want enter the patient data, and then i want to be able to give output after key in the id, this means that i use searching method, here i use linear search. i use array, to save the patient data, such as name and age. so in pharmacy department i want to be able to search the patient data before approving giving medicine.

```
#include<iostream.h>
int linear(int patient[],int size,int key);
int linear(int patient[],int size,int key) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
        if(key==patient[i].id) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

void main() {   
    int i=0;
    int size=2;
    struct patientRecord {
        char name[20];
        int id,age;
        int *patient;
    };
    patientRecord patient[i];
    int choice;
    cout<<"Welcome to Hospital Sejahtera\n";
    cout<<"Please enter your choice:";
    cout<<"1.Patient Registration\n2.Pharmacy\n3.Doctor Appoinment";
    cin>>choice;
    if(choice==1) {
        for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
            cout<<"Please enter patient name";
            cin>>patient[i].name;
            cout<<"Please enter patient id";
            cin>>patient[i].id;
            cout<<"Please enter patient age";
            cin>>patient[i].age;
        }
    } else if(choice==2) {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
            cout<<"Enter the patient id to search:";
            cin>>patient[i].id;
            linear(patient,size,patient[i].id);
            cout<<"Location at index:";
            cout<<endl; 
        }
    }
}
```

i would be glad if you all can point out my mistake. im still learning. please help.

Comment: Could you fix your formatting first?

Comment: `main` is required to return `int`. And there's a linear search in the standard library: `std::find`.

Comment: @kuntut: Yours, i.e. the formatting of your post.

Comment: The code has quite a lot of errors that a compiler will point out. Are there any particular error messages you don't understand? Is there a more specific problem we can help with?

Comment: @PeterSW, 'else if(choice==2)
 {
 int i,id;
  
  for(i=0;i<2;i++)
  cout<<"Enter the patient id to search:";
  cin>>patient[i].id;
   
  linear(patient,size,id);
  cout<<"Location at index:";
  cout<<endl; 
  
 }' i dont understand why it dont run the linear class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might get a compile warning here that the variable size is not used.
You should check out what that is and where it should go.

```
int linear(int patient[],int size,int key) {
int i;
for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
    if(key==patient[i].id) {
        return i;
    }
}
return -1;
}
```

Comment: Actually that somehow makes it worse. You do that, but never use it! Everytime you go through a loop, you don't use your defined size, but a hardcoded 2 - thus making the definition obsolete.

Comment: @dornhedge, tq for the enlighten.